# jquery selector / checked attribute doesn't update in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have a function that's called by a link which should check various checkboxes which exist inside a specific div (passed to the function.) Works in all browsers except IE (7.) As far as I can tell .attr('checked', 'checked' is the proper way to do this using jquery 1.5.1

```
function selectall(industry){
    $("#"+industry+"Apps :checkbox").attr('checked', 'checked');
    $("#"+industry+"Apps :checkbox").change(); /* used for jqtransform plugin */
    }
```

Is there something I'm missing or a better way to do this that works in all browsers? I don't really care about un-selecting, just selecting.

HTML looks like

```
<div id = 'HealthcareApps'>
<div style="clear: both;">
    <a href = "javascript:selectall('Healthcare');">Select all</a>
</div>
<ul>
    <li><label for="id_Healthcare_0"><input type="checkbox" name="Healthcare" value="1" id="id_Healthcare_0" /> Simple Messaging</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_Healthcare_1"><input type="checkbox" name="Healthcare" value="2" id="id_Healthcare_1" /> Mobile Alerts and Alarms</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_Healthcare_2"><input type="checkbox" name="Healthcare" value="3" id="id_Healthcare_2" /> Patient Identification / Drug Conflicts</label></li>
</ul>
```

(yes, I know inline styles are a horrible idea. I'll fix that as well if I can ever get this link to work in IE.)

Comment: How is `selectall()` being called? I see a `switchval()`...

Comment: oh whoops i renamed the function when I pasted in here so it made more sense and then didn't change the HTML. Changing it in the actual code now. Assume the code I'm actually testing is consistent lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this: [js fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hv5jk/2/)

```
<div id = 'HealthcareApps'>
<div style="clear: both;">
    <a href="#" id="selectall" class="Healthcare" >Select all</a>
</div>
<ul>
    <li><label for="id_Healthcare_0"><input type="checkbox" name="Healthcare" value="1" id="id_Healthcare_0" /> Simple Messaging</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_Healthcare_1"><input type="checkbox" name="Healthcare" value="2" id="id_Healthcare_1" /> Mobile Alerts and Alarms</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_Healthcare_2"><input type="checkbox" name="Healthcare" value="3" id="id_Healthcare_2" /> Patient Identification / Drug Conflicts</label></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('#selectall').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var industry = $(this).attr("class");
    $("#" + industry + "Apps :checkbox").attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

And, to toggle on and off:

```
$('#selectall').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var industry = $(this).attr("class");
    var checkbox = $("#" + industry + "Apps :checkbox");
    checkbox.attr('checked', !checkbox.attr('checked'));
});
```

[js fiddle toggle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hv5jk/4/)

Comment: interesting. I've been avoiding this problem all day but I'll definitely try this out.

Comment: just followed that link and verified that it works! Thanks so much! Hours of frustration were just whisked away!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function selectall(industry){
    $("#"+industry+"Apps :checkbox").attr('checked', true);
    $("#"+industry+"Apps :checkbox").change(); /* used for jqtransform plugin */
}
```

If you use jQuery 1.6+ you can use `prop`

```
$("#"+industry+"Apps :checkbox").prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using click() instead of change(). This seems to be an IE7 bug:

[IE7 issues with my jQuery [click and change functions]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720956/ie7-issues-with-my-jquery-click-and-change-functions)

Comment: I tried this to no avail. The thing is that the jqtransform plugin defines a function for the change() event.

however jqtransform also triggers the change event on click, so this should have worked but didn't?

(I also tried .trigger("change") and that didn't work in IE either.)

Comment: I think you'll have to tell the developer of jqtransform about the IE7 issue, then. But perhaps writing a click() event handler that triggers "change" will give you the best of both worlds?

Comment: yeah there are a few other things I'd like to see change about the plugin anyway, I'll definitely try to get in contat wit them. In the mean time you may be right - I'll give the custom .click() handler shot.

Answer (score 0):

try
    
        `$("#"+industry+"Apps input:checkbox").attr('checked', 'checked');`

I don't have time to verify this ( at work :) ) but I have a sneaking suspicion this will help ie7 figure it out

Answer (score 0):

In your markup, the 'HealthcareApps' div does not have a closing tag. Perhaps this is a copy/paste omission, but if it is not, then invalid markup could feasibly be the reason, especially since it's IE7 that is complaining.

Comment: accidentally omitted in pasting but good looking out. I guess I can check the rest of the markup as well but I'm fairly sure its already valid (although this would explain why none of the other suggestions would work...)